# symfony2 and symfony1 application same password encryption

Tags: php, security, symfony, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony1 application with sfGuardUser plugin. I need to use the same database in my new symfony2 application.

How should I define the password encoder so it match the symfony1 encoded passwords?

Comment: You just need to [take a look at the code](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/branches/1.3/lib/model/plugin/PluginsfGuardUser.php#L28) from sfGuard and apply the same rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't provide a different encoding algorithm back then Symfony 1.x would use `sha1($salt.$rawPassword)`. So your PasswordEncoder should look like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class PasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        return sha1($salt.$raw);
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        return $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt) === $encoded;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: You save me a day of debug very old project.